# Sublime Text 3 - Scroll Only Until the Last Line

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Whenever I scroll a file all the way to the bottom of a text file, it will scroll far beyond the last line, and I end up with a blank screen.
Then, to view the last lines of text, I have to scroll a little bit up, and in huge log files it usually gets scrolled too much.

I'll give an example.
When I scroll all the way down, this is what I expect to see:

> *560* lorem ipsum
>   *561* lorem ipsum
>   *562* lorem ipsum
>   *563* lorem ipsum
>   *564* lorem ipsum
>   *565* lorem ipsum
>   *566* lorem ipsum
>   *567* lorem ipsum
>   *568* lorem ipsum
>   *569* lorem ipsum
>   *570* lorem ipsum

But instead I see this:

> 

I know I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>. But what I would like to know, is if there a way to change the annoying behavior of scrolling 50+ lines too much.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There is a setting that controls this, which defaults to being turned on except on MacOS, where it is disabled by defaul:

```json
// Set to false to disable scrolling past the end of the buffer.
// On OS X, this value is overridden in the platform specific settings, so
// you'll need to place this line in your user settings to override it.
"scroll_past_end": true,
```

You can select `Preferences > Settings` from the menu and set the setting to `false` to disable this behaviour.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to determine how much or how many lines one can scroll _past the end_?

Comment: When the setting is turned on (as above) the scrolling stops when the last line of the file hits the top of the `view`, so the amount is based on how many lines are visible at once in your layout. From a plugin you could do `view.viewport_extent()[1] / view.line_height()` to determine how many lines are visible in the view at any given point in time, if that's what you mean. Subtracting `1` from that number would tell you how many whole lines you can scroll past. Note that fractional lines are possible (i.e. a line is partially scrolled in or out).